# Optionally omit select parameter from form submission

Tags: html, forms, select

Given an HTML form like:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="GET">
    Select:
    <select id="param" name="param">
        <option></option>
        <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="Value 3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I omit the parameter entirely from the form submission if the blank option is selected?

Comment: Can't you check the emptiness of the parameter instead?

Comment: You could just use JavaScript to remove the select element if the selected option is empty when the form is submitted.

Comment: @sp00m -- I'd prefer to omit the parameter in my case, not least because the resultant URL is simpler

Comment: You can use post method to hide the parameters from url..

Comment: @TilwinJoy -- it's semantically a GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted a pure JavaScript approach, something like this would remove the `name` attribute of the `select` element if the selected `option` value was empty before the form is submitted.

Just give the form element a name..

```
<form name="formName" method="GET"></form>
```

JS - [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1bwu67r7/)

```
document.forms["formName"].addEventListener('submit', function(){
    var el = this.querySelector('select[name="param"]');
    if(!el.value){
        el.removeAttribute('name');
    }
});
```

Alternatively, here is a jQuery version.. not much different.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vnnhykL/)

```
$('form[name="formName"]').submit(function(e){
    var el = $(this).find('select[name="param"]');
    if(!el.val()){
        el.removeAttr("name");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with this is that you get the visual effect of the select control disappearing. I ended up doing removeAttr("name") instead.

Comment: @user3364825 Alright, I edited my answer anyways. All I did was change that one line. I'd suggest going with the pure JS solution. You really don't need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with (JQuery):

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  if ($("#param").val() === "")
    $("#param").removeAttr("name");
});
```

It has the advantage that it doesn't visibly change the DOM immediately after clicking submit.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, you need Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function checkForm()
   {
     var paramVal = $('#param').val();
     if(paramVal == "0"){ return false;}
   }
</script>

<select name="param" id="param">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="Value 3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" onclick="return checkForm();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: your example prevents the form submission if the blank option is chosen. I still want to submit the form, but omit the parameter from the form submission.

Comment: Then you need to disable or remove the element from DOM before form submission. like $('#param').attr('disabled','disabled');

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function validate()
   {
 if ($("#param").val() == "")
    $("#param").removeAttr("name");
   }
</script>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
<select name="param" id="param">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="Value 3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```